# jQuery Animate to reshuffle divs to their targets?

Tags: jquery, css, position, jquery-animate

I have two grids of divs that are the same. One grid is absolute so it overlays the first. Think of the lower grid as targets. I'm trying to get the divs on the upper grid to animate position to their corresponding targets. While the animation works, it appears that it only works for one div and it's pushing all the others around. What I want is for each div to animate animate to their corresponding target position.

```js
$(".item").each(function(i) {

  var itemNumber = $(this).attr("id").substring(4);

  $("#item" + itemNumber).animate({
    top: $("#spot" + itemNumber).position().top,
    left: $("#spot" + itemNumber).position().left
  }, 3000);

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.contentWell {
  position: relative;
  width: 410px;
  height: 410px;
}
.listContent {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
#items {
  position: absolute;
}
.spot,
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.spot {
  border: 3px solid aqua;
  color: aqua;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="contentWell">
  <div id="spots" class="listContent">
    <div class="spot" id="spot0">0</div>
    <div class="spot" id="spot1">1</div>
    <div class="spot" id="spot2">2</div>
    <div class="spot" id="spot3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="items" class="listContent">
    <div class="item" id="item3">3</div>
    <div class="item" id="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item" id="item0">0</div>
    <div class="item" id="item2">2</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

A solution would be appreciated. An explanation would be monumental as I'm beyond flummoxed. Thanks.

Comment: Just a couple of proposals for you: **(1)** Look into **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)** for all your animation needs. **(2)** Avoid animating ***TRBL*** properties and instead always try to animate **`translate`** because it is **[more performant](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having **`position: absolute;`** instead of **`position: relative;`** in your CSS rule for **`.item`** elements would solve this issue because you want to position them *exactly* where there respective *spot* elements are. **`relative`** elements would always push each other here and there.

Oh and you can safely remove the **`#item { position: absolute; }`** line because its the children who need to be *absolutely* positioned and not the parent container element.

```js
$(".item").each(function(i) {

  var itemNumber = $(this).attr("id").substring(4);

  $("#item" + itemNumber).animate({
    top: $("#spot" + itemNumber).position().top,
    left: $("#spot" + itemNumber).position().left
  }, 3000);

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.contentWell {
  position: relative;
  width: 410px;
  height: 410px;
}
.listContent {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.spot,
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.spot {
  border: 3px solid aqua;
  color: aqua;
}
.item {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="contentWell">
  <div id="spots" class="listContent">
    <div class="spot" id="spot0">0</div>
    <div class="spot" id="spot1">1</div>
    <div class="spot" id="spot2">2</div>
    <div class="spot" id="spot3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="items" class="listContent">
    <div class="item" id="item3">3</div>
    <div class="item" id="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item" id="item0">0</div>
    <div class="item" id="item2">2</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Hope this helps.

***Update:***

Take a look at this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/7yoboaL9/)** for example. It sets initial positions of **`.item`** elements by picking up the *indices* of **`.spot`** elements and using their **`top`** and **`left`** values. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks Tahir, you are correct. However, with absolute the squares all start at the top left and animate. I need them to start at their existing locations and animate to their targets. So maybe my larger problem is figuring out how to do a grid layout with absolute positioning instead of relative?

Comment: then I think defining them initially via JavaScript would work as well. Initiate using `.css({...})` and then `.animate({...})` afterwards. Don't you think that would work?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on  "Initiate using .css({...})"?

Comment: added an **Update** above in my answer with a link to a fiddle.

Comment: Did it help @Layne? Did it explain the usage of `.css({...})` I was referring to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82719/discussion-between-tahir-ahmed-and-layne).